# Raising exceptions in Python within and outside of __init__ when defining new class

Tags: python

I have defined a class named Person with two attributes -- name and age. If age is above 40, I want to raise an exception. I am able to do this successfully within **init** as follows:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        if age > 40:
            raise ValueError('age too high')

    def get_list(self):
        return [self.name, self.age]

p1 = Person('Bob', 36)
p2 = Person('John', 55)
```

However, in larger problems, raising all exceptions (all value or type errors, in my case) within the **init** statement seems cumbersome and not good programming practice, especially since more than half of the total code I would have to write would be within the initializer. So I tried:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def _verify_age(self, age):
        if age > 40:
            raise ValueError('age too high')

    def get_list(self):
        return [self.name, self.age]

p1 = Person('Bob', 36)
p2 = Person('John', 55)
```

But defining `p2` does not raise the 'age too high' error, as before.

How can I solve this? I am still new to classes and am still trying to find the best alternative to the first block of code.

Comment: You have not called `_verify_age` function

Comment: You never call your `_verify_age` function, why do you expect it to do anything?

Comment: Where should I call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only defined the function, and never called it.

You can try:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self._verify_age()

    def _verify_age(self):
        if self.age > 40:
            raise ValueError('age too high')

    def get_list(self):
        return [self.name, self.age]
```

Comment: Tried this, but after ```p1 = Person('Bob', 36)```, I get: ```TypeError: _verify_age() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given```

Comment: There's a typo in `__init__`, you don't need to pass `self` manually like that.

Comment: Sorry, now getting ```_verify_age() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given```

Comment: @MathewCarroll: Try now

Comment: Now its ```_verify_age() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: @MathewCarroll: Modified again. Please check now